# Show Hyphen only if Token exists

Tags: path-aliases

I use [URL Alias](https://www.drupal.org/project/url_alias) an have set to construct the URL based on 2 tokens:

```
[node:token1]-[node:token2].html
```

Those two tokens are connected with a hyphen *"-"*.

Sometimes the second token (token2) is not present (empty) and in this case I want to show only token1, without hyphen, but it creates even then:

```
http://token1-.html
```

How can i configure it to show only:

```
http://token1.html
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution? I'm also running into the same situation.